# How to install an AC bracket without a windowsill

Tags: windows, air-conditioning, mounting, brackets

These instructions call for anchoring the AC bracket to the window sill, right where it meets the stool:

[image: instruction image]

However, my windows don't have that layout, here's a picture of what mine looks like:

[image]

[image]

How should I attach this? The instructions don't help me with this type of window sill.

Comment: I'm having the same issue! Did you find a solution? I was hoping that I'd find the answer here.

Comment: Yes, I ended up drilling into the windowsill on the outside and then installing some right angle metal brackets. That worked very well for me. I returned the one pictured above.